# When to use IO[str]/IO[bytes] and TextIO/BinaryIO in Python type hinting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

From the documentation, it says that:

> Generic type `IO[AnyStr]` and its subclasses `TextIO(IO[str])` and `BinaryIO(IO[bytes])` represent the types of I/O streams such as returned by `open()`.
>
> — Python Docs: [`typing.IO`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.IO)

The docs did not specify when `BinaryIO`/`TextIO` shall be used over their counterparts `IO[str]` and `IO[bytes]`.

Through a simple inspection of the Python Typeshed source, only [30 hits](https://github.com/python/typeshed/search?q=BinaryIO&unscoped_q=BinaryIO) found when searching for `BinaryIO`, and [109 hits](https://github.com/python/typeshed/search?q=IO%5Bbytes%5D&unscoped_q=IO%5Bbytes%5D) for `IO[bytes]`.

I was trying to switch to `BinaryIO` from `IO[bytes]` for better compatibility with [sphinx-autodoc-typehints](https://github.com/agronholm/sphinx-autodoc-typehints), but the switch-over has broken many type checks as methods like `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` is typed as `IO[bytes]` instead of the other.

Design-wise speaking, what are the correct situations to use each type of these IO type hints?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`BinaryIO` and `TextIO` directly subclass `IO[bytes]` and `IO[str]` respectively, and add on a few extra methods -- see the [definitions in typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/64bc0590a6615266180b5640c730f62f8ad84d04/stdlib/typing.pyi#L686) for the specifics.

So if you need these extra methods, use `BinaryIO/TextIO`. Otherwise, it's probably best to use `IO[...]` for maximum flexibility. For example, if you annotate a method as accepting an `IO[str]`, it's a bit easier for the end-user to provide an instance of that object.

Though all this being said, the IO classes in general are kind of messy at present: they define a lot of methods that not all functions will actually need. So, the typeshed maintainers are actually considering [breaking up the IO class into smaller Protocols](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/564). You could perhaps do the same, if you're so inclined. This approach is mostly useful if you want to define your own IO-like classes but don't want the burden of implementing the full `typing.IO[...]` API -- or if you're using some class that's almost IO-like, but not quite.

All this being said, all three approaches -- using `BinaryIO/TextIO`, `IO[...]`, or defining more compact custom Protocols -- are perfectly valid. If the sphinx extension doesn't seem to be able to handle one particular approach for some reason, that's probably a bug on their end.